# Can you solve the "kinds of TMs" problem?

Tags: turing-machines

there are 3 kinds of TMs

1. a Halting TM on all inputs prints finitely many symbols on it's output tape and halts
2. a Circle-free TM on all inputs prints infinitely many symbols on it's output tape
3. a Crashy TM is neither Circle-free nor Halting (if a TM reject any input it's Crashy)

[image: the kinds of TMs]

"the kinds of TMs" problem is to find a Crashy TM that computes the following function that uses crashing as a way to signal when the function is "undefined"

$$
\begin{align*}
k(m) &=
   \begin{cases}
     1 & \text{if $m$ is a Halting TM} \\
     0 & \text{if $m$ is a Circle-free TM} \\
     undefined & \text{if $m$ is a Crashy or invalid TM}
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

I hope the implication of having a solution to this problem is obvious to everybody, it makes programming a lot more fun and easier

can you solve this problem?

to be clear this problem is different than Halting problem and Satisfactoriness problem

- Halting problem ask for a Halting TM to see whether $m$ is a Halting TM or Non-Halting TM
- Satisfactoriness problem ask for a Halting TM to see whether $m$ is Circular or Circle-free
- Kinds of TMs problem ask for a **Crashy TM** to see whether $m$ is Halting or Crashy or Circle-free

and you can NOT solve them by each other

it worth mentioning that there are 13 different kinds of Crashy TMs, I'm looking for a Hashi TM

1. a Crashi TM on all inputs after some times crash (stop moving the tape or tapes)
2. a Loopy TM on all inputs loops without printing infinitely many symbols on it's output tape
3. a Loopi TM is a Loopy TM that on some inputs crash
4. a Hashi TM is a Halting TM that on some inputs crash
5. ...

Comment: Isn't there a trivial reduction from the halting problem?

Comment: @Nathaniel it seems to me there isn't any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a crashy-TM that computed $k$ we could use it to decide this version of the halting problem, which is known to be undecidable: given a Turing machine $T$, does $T$ halt on empty input?

You can see this by noticing that, given any Turing machine $T$, you can construct a new Turing machine $T'$ that 1) halts if and only if $T$ halts, 2) if $T$ does not halt, then $T'$ prints infinitely many symbols. In your nomenclature, either $T'$ halts (iff $T$ halts) or it is circle free.

To build $T'$ from $T$ we will simulate $T$ while ensuring that each transition of $T$ writes at least a new non-blank tape symbol.
To guarantee this, we will make use of an additional tape symbol $\bot$. This symbol is not the blank tape symbol (which will be denoted as $\varepsilon$), but will behave similarly to $\varepsilon$ for the sake of simulating the tranistions of $T$.
We will also allow symbols on the tape to be "marked", which can be done by duplicating the tape alphabet (i.e., each symbol has a "marked" and a "unmarked" variant). There will be at most one marked symbol at each point in time, and it will be used to remember the head position in the simulation of $T$.
We proceed as follows:

1. Clear the tape (i.e., replace all input symbols with $\varepsilon$).
2. Simulate a transition of $T$ interpreting any read $\bot$< as $\varepsilon$. If the transition of $T$ would cause $\varepsilon$ to be written on the tape, then write $\bot$ instead.
3. Mark the current tape location.
4. Move right until you find the first blank symbol $\varepsilon$, replace it with $\bot$.
5. Move left until you locate the marked tape location and unmark it.
6. Repeat from step 2 until $T$ halts (possibly forever).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140105/discussion-on-answer-by-steven-can-you-solve-the-kinds-of-tms-problem).

Comment: @D.W. the discussion was about the correctness of the answer, does that count as extended discussion?

Comment: Yes.  If you're looking for discussion or extended interactive back-and-forth, that isn't a good fit for this site's format.

Comment: @D.W. actually it fits just fine - even though some executives from on high claimed that it didn't. The "click to view more comments" button is what makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I should mention that your picture is not correct. Probably the correct picture is as follows:[image]

Secondly, the answer to your question about whether we can find a TM that computes the $k(m)$ functions is negative.
Before giving the reason and proof let's fix some expressions.
By the language of a TM $T$ I mean the following set:

$$\mathcal{L}(T) = \{s\in \Sigma^*\mid \text{when we run Turing machine } T \text{ given input } s \text{ it goes into accept state and halts.}\}$$

where $\Sigma$ is a set of input symbols.

The reason is the following reduction:

First, consider Turing Machine $M'$ that acts as follows:

1. Turing Machine $M'$ takes two inputs $m, w'$.
2. Check if $w=w'$ ($w$ is a fixed string in its memory for Machine $M'$)

   if $w\neq w'$ it go into reject state and halts.

   if $w=w'$ it run TM with coding $m$ with input $w'$ and go into accept state and halt, if $m$ goes into accept state and halt.

It is obvious that the *language* of TM $M'$ is $\{w\}$ if TM with coding $m$ accepts $w$, and otherwise, it is empty (Since in this case $M'$ went into a loop, or crashed or ...)

Now, assume that there is a Turing machine $K$ that computes $k(m)$ you have defined in your question that is

$$k(m)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \text{m is halting}\\ 0 & \text{m is circle free}\\undefined & \text{m is crashy or invalid} \end{array}\right.$$

Whenever we give coding of Turing machine $M'$ (assume it is $m'$) then we expect that $K$ return $0$ if $L(M')=\{w\}$ and return $1$ or $undefined$ otherwise..

So where is the problem?
consider the following language:

$$\mathcal{A}_{TM} = \{(m,w)\mid \text{When we run Turing machine } m \text{ on input } w \text{ it goes to accept state and halt.}\}$$

By having Turing machine $K$, we can decide the above language which is undecideable! How? We simply on input $(m,w)$ devise the coding of Turing machine $M'$ defined in above, give this encoding $m'$ to the Turing machine $K$ and Hey! We decide whether $m$ accept $w$ or not!

You can check the proof of undecidability of $\mathcal{A}_{TM}$ in the book with title: ``[Introduction to Theory of computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113318779X)" page 202 Theorem 4.11.

What we have did? We have the reduction $\mathcal{A}_{TM}\leq L(K)$ (Check corollary 5.23 in the above book.)

By the way, can you tell humans characteristics from their outfit and appearance? It seems not. The same is here for Turing machines. You are not able to tell that a Turing machine $m$ can halt or crash or stuck into infinity just by its syntax! you need to look at its behaviour, and so if it goes into infinity, you probably stuck into infinity too.

Comment: I guess I draw the diagram poorly but it is correct it suppose to divide the rectangle into 4 parts and each text is bounded by that part. I say a TM crash when it reject an input so your $M'$  is a Crashy TM so $k(m')=undefined$ (you misunderstood my definitions)

Comment: Nope, I think you didn't get the idea. We have lots of possible $M'$, and when the language of $L(M')$ is $\{w\}$ the $M'$ always halts!!! do not make it mistake with other possible $M'$ with other fixed values $w$. So TM $K$ should always answer $0$ for that special $M'$. If it returns undefined it means that $M'$ sometimes halts, and sometimes does not halt, right? but which $M'$? Please say what happened to the $M'$ always halts then? shouldn't $K$ return something about it?

Comment: all $M'$s with different value for $w$ are Crashy TMs because they reject some of their inputs (I consider rejecting as crashing), the way you defined $M'$s, no $M'$ halts for all of it's inputs

Comment: I think you are abusing the term "Halting" and editing your question again. But it does not matter. Your defined function again is uncomputable since then we can reduce the language known as TOT to the language of K (see book Computability-complexity-and-languages-Fundamentals-of-theoretical-computer-science Theorem 6.1 or For another example see Corollary 5.2 in the book A Mathematical Sketchbook -Graduate Texts in Mathematics). Also, I suggest you read Rice theorem to obtain better intuition on uncomputable functions and programs.

Comment: I accepted the other answer you can try to find a counter example for my new question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154925/can-you-solve-the-crashy-tms-problem-it-seems-easier-than-kinds-of-tms-pro). TMs don't need to have reject states you can reject by crashing (keep reading a symbol without moving the tape)