# Is the combined set of halting and circle-free Turing machines recursively enumerable?

Tags: turing-machines

this question is related to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154852/can-you-solve-the-kinds-of-tms-problem) question but it's different

there are 3 kinds of TMs

1. a Halting TM on all inputs prints finitely many symbols on it's output tape and halts
2. a Circle-free TM on all inputs prints infinitely many symbols on it's output tape
3. a Crashy TM is neither Circle-free nor Halting (if a TM reject any input it's Crashy)

[image: the kinds of TMs]

"the Crashy TMs" problem is to find a **Crashy TM** that computes the following function

$$
\begin{align*}
c(m) &=
   \begin{cases}
     0 & \text{if $m$ is a Halting or Circle-free TM} \\
     undefined & \text{if $m$ is a Crashy or invalid TM}
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

I hope the implication of having a solution to this problem is obvious to everybody, it makes programming a lot more fun and easier

can you solve this problem?

it worth mentioning that there are 13 different kinds of Crashy TMs, I'm looking for a Hashi TM

1. a Crashi TM on all inputs after some times crash (stop moving the tape or tapes)
2. a Loopy TM on all inputs loops without printing infinitely many symbols on it's output tape
3. a Loopi TM is a Loopy TM that on some inputs crash
4. a Hashi TM is a Halting TM that on some inputs crash
5. ...

Comment: "A crashy TM is neither Circle-free or Halting"  I don't understand why it is shown in the intersection of the two in your Venn diagram? Further, why does "rejecting any input" (I presume, meaning rejecting *every* possible string in finite time) make a TM crashy?

Comment: @kviiri I guess my drawing is not good, the diagram suppose to divide the rectangle into 4 parts and each text is bounded by that part

Comment: @kviiri sorry I didn't see your last edit, that is just my definition, my TMs don't have reject states so to reject an input you have to go into an infinite loop (keep reading the tape without moving it) so rejecting and crashing are the same things

Comment: "undefined" means any value is acceptable including non-termination. Therefore, the algorithm $c(m) = 0$ meets your requirements.

Comment: @user253751 no "undefined" means the algorithm does not halt

Comment: @raoof I see. For the record, problems that can be "half-solved" like this are called [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_(complexity)).

Comment: @raoof what if it moves left and then moves right and then moves left and then moves right...?

Comment: with that in mind I proposed editing the title and I think this is actually a reasonable question. This problem *might* turn out to be an easy one, somehow, since all of the obvious "difficult" halting problem cases are still obviously either halting or circle-free!

Comment: @user253751 finally someone understood what I'm asking, thanks. if a TM move the tape left and then right and then left and then right forever it's crashy

Answer (score 0):

Consider this version of the halting problem: given an input Turing machine $T$, decide whether $T$ halts on empty input. You can assume that $T$ is a valid description of a TM. This problem is known to be undecidable.

My answer in [your other question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154852/can-you-solve-the-kinds-of-tms-problem/154853), provides a way to build a Turing machine $T'$ from $T$ such that 1) $T'$is either halting or circle-free, and 2) $T'$ halts if and only if $T$ halts (on empty input).
For the sake of keeping this answer self-contained, the idea of $T'$ is that of simulating $T$ while making sure that a new symbol (that will be treated as a blank for the sake of the simulation) is appended at the end of the tape after each step.

Construct a Turing machine $T''$ that ignores its input, simulates $T'$, and then (if the simulation ever ends) enters in a loop without printing any new symbol.

There are two cases:

- If $T$ halts (on empty input) then $T'$ also halts. Therefore $T''$ is crashy since it does not halt and only prints finitely many symbols, hence $c(T'')=1$.
- If $T$ does not halt, then $T'$ is circle-free and so is $T''$. Therefore $c(T'')=0$.

This means that $c(\cdot)$ is not computable, since it would allow us to decide whether $T$ halts (on empty input) and solve the above version of the halting problem.

Comment: someone said comments are not for discussion but anyway as I said in the chat you haven't specified how you simulate the transition of $T$, you have to write a universal TM $u'(m)$ that takes $T$ and returns $T'$ I hope it's obvious that $u'$ is Crashy so any TM that uses $u'$ is going to be Crashy ($T'(m)=u'(T)$), if you are interested we can continue the discussion in the chat

Comment: Using an universal TM with a hardcoded description of $T$ to be simulated is an option, but you don't have to go to this length. It suffices to show that there is an algorithm (i.e., a TM) that takes a description of $T$ and produces a description of $T'$. This is easy to do since the transitions of $T'$ are mostly those of $T$. The same thing goes for building (a description of) $T''$ from a description of $T'$. Writing down the transformation down to each transition is tedious, so I'm not going to go in that level of detail. It should be clear that $T'$ and $T''$ can be built.

Comment: yes there is an algorithm for each individual case just like there is an algorithm for each individual case of halting problem so you didn't prove anything

Comment: @raoof I strongly disagree. The existence of an algorithm that takes $T$ (resp. $T'$) as an input and produces $T'$ (resp. $T''$) is enough. I do not wish to entertain this discussion further.

Comment: just for the future readers you don't need to respond to this, if I give you a $T$ that keeps printing $0$ without moving the tape I consider that a Crashy TM and your constructed $T'$ and $T''$ are going to be Crashy as well

Comment: @raoof. No. What you say is false. $T'$ and $T''$ are both going to print infinitely many non-blank symbols on infinitely many different locations of the tape (while $T$ only prints in a single location).

Comment: I guess you are right about my first question but you are wrong about my second question, I changed $c(m)$ to $c(m)=undefined$ if $m$ is a Crashy TM, can you find a counter example for this question?

Comment: Please do not edit the question into a different question after receiving an answer.

Comment: sorry my bad, I just learn as I go so I can't keep asking different question I already get a down vote I guess because somebody thought this is the same question as "the kinds of TMs" question

Comment: If we know that T' is either halting or circle-free then c(T')=0 - no questions asked. This is computable even if we don't know which one it is.

Comment: @user253751 the question was different when the answer was posted.

Comment: Even the old version is not trivially reducible to the halting problem. Even in the old version of the question, if we know T' is either halting or circle-free, then c(T')=0. You might have confused it with a different question, which you linked to.

Comment: I did not confuse the questions. Consider the 1st version *this* question.
$T''$ is halting or circle-free (in particular it is circle-free) iff $T$ doesn't halt on (empty input), in which case $c(T'')=0$. $T''$ is crashy or invalid (in particular, crashy) iff $T$ halts, i.e., $c(T'')=1$. Computing $c(T'')$ allows to decide whether $T$ halts. This is a well-known undecidable problem, therefore $c$ is not computable. I edited my answer because $0$ and $1$ were swapped w.r.t. the original definition of $c$, but notice that argument works for any choice of 2 distinct values for the cases of $c$.

Comment: When T'' is crashy then the computation of c(T'') is not required to halt.

Comment: It was in the original version of this question. $c(M)$ was defined as $1$ when $M$ is crashy.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [the previous one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154852/can-you-solve-the-kinds-of-tms-problem/154903?noredirect=1#comment325801_154903) if you had pondered about it.
I wonder if you paid attention to my last comment about Rice's theorem and my [last sentences in the answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154852/can-you-solve-the-kinds-of-tms-problem/154903#154903) or not, but to help you I rewrite Rice's theorem statement [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) (Also you can read about this theorem in almost all computability books):

> In computability theory, Rice's theorem states that all non-trivial
> semantic properties of programs are undecidable. A semantic property
> is one about the program's behavior (for instance, does the program
> terminate for all inputs), unlike a syntactic property (for instance,
> does the program contain an if-then-else statement). A property is
> non-trivial if it is neither true for every partial computable
> function nor false for every partial computable function.

So simply by Rice's theorem the function $c(m)$ you have defined in this question and also the $k(m)$ you have defined in the [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154852/can-you-solve-the-kinds-of-tms-problem/154903?noredirect=1#comment325801_154903) which tries to find the semantic behavior of Turing machine is uncomputable.

Comment: Rice's theorem only proves that you can not have a total computable function for solving a semantic property, it does NOT say anything about having a sometimes effective solution, my question asks for a sometimes effective solution

Comment: @raoof I rewrite the following sentences from the book "Computational Complexity a modern approach", page 35, Exc 1.12: "If $S$ is a set of partial functions, we define
$f_S$ to be the Boolean function that on input $\alpha$ outputs 1 iff $M_\alpha$ computes a partial function in $S$. Rice’s Theorem says that for every nontrivial $S$ (a set that is not the empty set nor the set of all partial functions computable by some Turing machine), the function $f_S$ is not computable.

Comment: my function is not a Boolean function, let me ask my question in a different way: is the set of uncrashy TMs recursively enumerable? . my question is like the following question: is the set of halting TMs on blank input recursively enumerable? yes $h'(m)=\{u(m,0);return\;1\}$ where $u(m,n)$ is a universal TM

Comment: I guess now I have figured out what your problem is. Are you familiar with the difference between recursive and recursive enumerable? the function $c(m)$ you have defined in your question is recursive enumerable but it is not recursive. The recursive set are equivalent to computable set, and the recursive enumerable set is equivalent to Semi-Computable (or recognizable set). You can not have a *computing* algorithm for something that is semi-computable,

Comment: this is from wikipedia: "In computability theory, a set S of natural numbers is called computably enumerable (c.e.), recursively enumerable (r.e.), semidecidable, partially decidable, listable, provable or Turing-recognizable if: There is an algorithm such that the set of input numbers for which the algorithm halts is exactly S." and I also gave an example $h'(m)$

Comment: Hey, I italic the computing term before algorithm if you have paid attention. COMPUTING means both reject and accept. but SEMI-COMPUTABLE means just accept. AND what you are asking continuously is COMPUTING. There are TM that are SEMI_computable which equivalent to R.E.

Comment: از اسمت حدس می‌زنم فارسی بلد باشی. به نظرم درس‌هات رو خوب یاد نگرفتی. به جهت اینکه متوجه اشتباهت بشی می‌نویسم. اینکه ماشین تورینگ داشته باشیم به این معنی نیست که لزوما بشه محاسبه کرد. محاسبه یه تعریف فرمال و خاص داره. برای محاسبه کردن ما نباید کرش کنیم یا توی لوپ بیفتیم. وقتی عبارت محاسبه کردن رو بکار می‌بریم یعنی قطعا و یقینا و حتما می‌تونیم بگیم که ورودی فلان عضو زبان هست یا نیست. اما شبه محاسبه اینه که شما هی بی خودی داری پافشاری می‌کنی که محاسبه پذیر هست. شبه محاسبه یعنی فقط برای ورودی های همون زبان تشخیص می‌دیم ولی اگه چیزی توی لوپ بیفته یا گیر کنه ما هم گیر می‌کنیم.

Comment: توجه کن اگه می‌تونستیم گیر کردن رو تشخیص بدیم که دیگه همه چیز عالم محاسبه‌پذیر میشد! ولی همه چیز عالم محاسبه پذیر نیست!!

Comment: و اون $h'$ ای که ارائه کردی دقیقا شبه محاسبه پذیر هست
یعنی چی؟ یعنی یه ماشین تورینگ هست که بگه بله ولی یک ماشین تورینگ نیست که هم بگه بله و هم بگه نه!

تاکید می‌کنم که به صفت‌ها و عبارت‌هایی که توی دنیای علوم کامپیوتر داری استفاده می‌کنی دقت کنی. الگوریتم محاسبه کردن با صرفا داشتن یک الگوریتم خیلی فرق داره. اولی حتما بله و خیر میگه دومی صرفا بله میگه

Comment: in terminology that you are using I'm looking for a semi-computable algorithm for $c(m)$, are you interested in finding one? please write in english so other people can also read

Comment: The point you are not getting is that in semi-computable TM there is no deciding part for the undefined part. You will get stuck as it is undefined. For your language $h'$ it is very simple! just run $m$ on blank input and see if it stopped and accepts, you will stop and return 1. And I should mention that I'm not interested in answering you anymore.

Comment: P. S. The terminology of semi-computable is used by computer scientists. It's very easy to check it on Wikipedia and other books. Also, I have mentioned recognizable, You can check that too.

Comment: imagine two secret formula, $isCrashy(m)$ and $isUncrashy(m)$ that are always true when they are $1$ then we can compute $c(m)$ like this 
$$
\begin{align*}
c(m) &=
   \begin{cases}
      undefined & if\;isCrashy(m)=isUncrashy(m) \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$. anyway thank you for your time

Comment: that's not quite write, to make it more readable rename $isCrashy$ to $maybeCrashy$ and $isUncrashy$ to $maybeUncrash$ and $c(m)$ to $isCrashy(m)$ then assuming we have $maybeCrashy$ and $maybeUncrashy$ we can compute $isCrash(m)$ as follows
$$
\begin{align*}
isCrashy(m) &=
   \begin{cases}
      undefined & if\;maybeCrashy(m)=1\;and\;maybeUncrashy(m)=0 \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Rice's theorem does not apply here because we are not asking for a total function to compute a property, but something weaker: a recursively enumerable set. Rice's theorem also does not apply, because to quote Wikipedia, "Rice's theorem does not concern the properties of machines or programs... For example, whether a machine runs for more than 100 steps on a particular input is a decidable property, even though it is non-trivial." and we are asking to determine a property of a machine or program. Therefore I downvoted this answer.

Comment: @user253751 I do not agree with you about the quote from Wikipedia. The property asked in the question is not necessarily the machine property. You can think of a TM that checks Goldbach's conjecture of all even numbers, that is if find an even number that does not satisfy the conjecture, halt and otherwise checks the next even number. If you were able to decide the halting or circle free you could decide and solve the Goldbach conjecture. I think the point people usually miss here is that in such examples, finding the loop does not relate to program syntax but the number theory if condition.

Comment: @user253751 Also, again I do not agree with your sentence that we are asking for something weaker. If the asker does not change his question again, you can see he is saying the term "Crashy TM that *computes* the following function". In Theoretical CS, when are asking for something *to be computed*, we want both accepting and rejecting so it is not weaker.

Comment: @Doralisa what does it mean to "compute undefined"?

Comment: @user253751 it is not *computing* then. Computing means we can have the answer for all inputs. The correct term is either designing a semi-computable function or a recognizer or a partial computable function.

Comment: @Doralisa you may propose an edit to correct the terminology in the question.

Comment: @user253751 Probably if the asker wanted, he could have changed the question by adding an edit part below his question and explaining that by computing the function he means half computing since there was a similar discussion in the comments of this answer with him himself as well.